# Intuitive problem with k-fold cross validation

Tags: r, machine-learning, linear-regression, cross-validation

I have some intuitive problems with checking prediction power with cross validation, I think I don't get the algorithm in 100%. 
I want to tell my intuitive problems on example. Let k=5 (number of folds) and

```
library(caret)
x=runif(100) 
z=rexp(100)
y=rnorm(100) 
Q=data.frame(x,z,y) 
train.control <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5)
train(y~x+z,method="lm",data=Q,trControl=train.control)
```

And in output I got :

```
100 samples
  2 predictor

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (5 fold) 
Summary of sample sizes: 80, 80, 80, 80, 80 
Resampling results:

  RMSE      Rsquared   MAE      
  1.032508  0.1272826  0.8213676

Tuning parameter 'intercept' was held constant at a value of TRUE
```

and my questions are :

(1) why my sample was divided on subsamples with lengths : 80,80,80,80,80 instead of 20,20,20,20,20 ? 
Length y,x and z is 100 not 400.

(2) algorithm is drawing just from x and z or from x and y and z ?

(3) what does the algorithm do after randomizing ? I cannot find anything about that in internet. I only saw that he calculates RMSE and MAE. But for example MAE calculates absolute value of differences between y and y.hat. I believe that h.hat are values predictive by model y~x+z (for example if i draw x=0.05 and z=0.16 then y.hat=0.21). But I have no idea what is the y for those draw numbers and I can't imagine possibility to choose correct one.

Please, can you answer my intuitive problems or just give me some good page to read about it ? In all pages I did read I couldn't find solutions to my problems. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. 5 fold CV means you divide the data in 5 parts, train 4 parts and test on 1 remaining part. Hence you train on 80 and test on remaining 20. And you do this 5 times for different 20s. You can check out this [vignette on cross-validation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html), i basically grab a diagram from there:

[image]

2. It samples the rows of your data frame. The x y and z has to go together and cannot be sampled independently, otherwise it's quite nonsense right.
3. You specified `method="lm"` and `y~x+z` so you fitted a linear model with y as the dependent variable and x and z as independent variable. Every time you draw a sample of 80, the coefficient of the model will (should) be different because of the samples draw. You predict the values for the test set and calculate the errors , RMSE or MAE. And after 5 rounds, we have the RMSE or MAE for 5 test sets and we take an average. Normally we do this iteratively for different hyper paramaters of a model to choose the best paramter, based on lowest error. But in your example, there is no hyper parameter to tune. You can check this nice [introduction to statistical learning textbook](http://faculty.marshall.usc.edu/gareth-james/ISL/)

Comment: That you very much for your explanation! Now I understand algorithm in 100%!